# android how to crete new folder using alert dialog in memory

Tags: android

i want to create new folder on button click using alert dialog take name form user and create folder on directory [as shown in this image](http://www.google.com.pk/imgres?q=android%20create%20new%20folder%20on%20alert&start=129&sa=X&hl=en&biw=992&bih=598&tbm=isch&tbnid=i5cXrx_VTKjORM%3a&imgrefurl=http://www.techradar.com/news/phone-and-communications/mobile-phones/50-really-useful-android-tips-and-tricks-709569&docid=nQ6PcZ8zKCikZM&imgurl=http://cdn3.mos.techradar.com///classifications/gadgets/phones/mobile-phones/Android/androidtips/rename_folders-320-100.jpg&w=320&h=480&ei=QWxuUYioJMqOrge9xYDoBA&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=763&vpy=56&dur=546&hovh=275&hovw=183&tx=121&ty=135&page=7&tbnh=159&tbnw=110&ndsp=22&ved=1t:429,r:34,s:100,i:106).

How can I create a new folder on dialog bar?

Please tell me what do i do?? how i create new folder using dialog

This is my file path where i want to create folder:

```
File photos = new File(getFilesDir(),"photos");
   photos.mkdir();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code for creating the folder looks correct. To get the folder name from the user you would need to do the following:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

alert.setTitle("Title");
alert.setMessage("Message");

// Set an EditText view to get user input 
final EditText input = new EditText(this);
alert.setView(input);

alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
       String value = input.getText();
       // Do something with value!

       //This is where you would put your make directory code
       File photos = new File(getFilesDir(),value);
       photos.mkdir();
    }
});

alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        // Canceled.
    }
});

alert.show();
```

Code sample modified from http://www.androidsnippets.com/prompt-user-input-with-an-alertdialog

It is normally good practice to check if a directory exists already before trying to create a new one. To do this, replace your create directory code

```
String value = "directory to create"
File photos = new File(getFilesDir(),value);

if(!photos.exists())
{
    if(photos.mkdir()) 
      {
       //directory is created;
      }
}
```

Comment: how to refresh grid after create folder

Comment: What do you mean by the grid?

Comment: GridView has an [InvalidateViews()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#invalidateViews()) method. This will cause all the views to be rebuilt and redrawn.